# In which timezone does psql display "timestamp without timezone"?

Tags: postgresql, psql, timestamp

What I mean is the following: if I create a `timestamp without timezone` (`timestamp`) column and store there some value, internally microseconds are stored, but when issuing `select` this is converted to a string with date and time. But in which timezone the converted time is?
I tried to change timezone in my computer (PostgreSQL is running locally, so I reopened `psql`), tried changing it in `postgresql.conf` (restarting the service) and setting timezone per session. However as far as I saw, the output doesn't change. I'm sure I'm missing something. Thanks!

Sample code:

```
create table tzo (wotz timestamp);
insert into tzo values (now());
table tzo;
```

Output:

```
            wotz            
----------------------------
 2020-08-11 17:51:37.244901
(1 row)
```

Comment: The session time zone: `show timezone;`

Comment: Could you run date command in OS and print timestamp in psql session at nearly the same time to investigate further and then match both the outputs with the world clock.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is not in the `session` timezone, unfortunately.`set timezone='Europe/Berlin';
table tzo;
            wotz            
----------------------------
 2020-08-11 17:51:37.244901
(1 row)
` (I'm obviously in different timezone with different offset)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know that this kind of timestamp doesn't store timezone. However, as far as I understand, conversion to string HAVE to use some timezone (let's say, UTC) to show something meaningful. I'm trying actually to match info from DB that came from client that is in a different timezone with my local time. When, say, in psql I see 6:00 PM, is it 6 PM in client's zone/mine/UTC/whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestamp without time zone` is time zone agnostic, so it is not adjusted to any time zone on display. This data type just doesn't have a time zone.

You can convert it to a certain time zone with `AT TIME ZONE`:

```
SHOW timezone;

   TimeZone    
---------------
 Europe/Vienna
(1 row)

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2020-08-01 12:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

        timezone        
------------------------
 2020-08-01 14:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Then the timestamp is interpreted as Viennese time, converted to UTC and displayed in my local Viennese time zone, which is offset two hours.

Comment: Let's concentrate on the first part of your answer, please. I do realize `timestamp` doesn't have timezone info attached, however, as far as my familiarity with programming goes, conversion to string always uses one or another, so I may realize an answer "it is converted as if the input was done in UTC, the output is also always like in UTC, but no offset is added when the output is displayed, no matter in which timezone the server or the `psql` client run". Then it may make sense ( I hope :) )

Comment: Essentially it means that what is written in timezone X as time 'A:B C:D' will always be represented as 'A:B C:D', no matter in which timezone Y the output is displayed (without any explicit conversions, only as far as the implementation in `psql` goes!)

Comment: I don't know why you insist on involving time zones into something where there are none. If that is easier to understand for you, imagine that there is only a single time zone, UTC if you want, and everything is done in that time zone - but there will be no time zone in the output.

Comment: That is because visual representation of Date has no meaning without timezone. It is perfectly possible though, that in whatever programming language PostgreSQL or `psql` are written, the conversion of Date to string may be done with `null` as a timezone. For Java or JavaScript there are fallbacks in such a case - a local one, or 'GMT', if no local is defined. What was crucial for me to understand is that if `timestamp` has `09:00PM` it will be presented as is no matter in which timezone I do `select` from

Comment: You are wrong. It is perfectly correct to say "At 2000-01-01 00:00:00, most people celebrated the new millennium" without any reference to a time zone.

Comment: And it will be relevant only for your timezone - Vienna, but not for me, as I celebrated it earlier, as my time offset is greater. The number of microseconds that passed from 01/01/1970 UTC is different for the Millenium in Austria, than it is for Millenium in my local timezone

Comment: No, you also celebrated at 2000-01-01 00:00:00, that is my point. Of course that may be a different absolute timestamp for you - a timestamp without time zone does *not* denote an absolute timestamp.

Comment: OK, the absolute timestamp is what interested me in this case. Sorry if it wasn't clear